# How can I call same API multiple time using MVVM in android?

Tags: android, mvvm

I have implemented MVVM architecture in one of my projects. In which I have created a ViewModel, Repository, and ViewModelFactory to make API call. I'm showing a list of products on the wish list. There is a facility where you can remove a particular product from the wish list. When my activity opens its API calls and renders the data but when I remove the product from the recycler view list need to make an API call which gets the remaining list of products available in the wishlist. When I change the configuration of the device it also makes API calls. How can I survive the configuration changes?

**Below is the code from Activity**

```
    val repository = WishlistRepository(activity)
    wishlistViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
        this,
        WishlistViewModelFactory(repository)
    )[WishlistViewModel::class.java]

    wishlistObservables()

    if (preferenceUtils.getPrefBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN)) {
        if (wishlistViewModel.wishListLiveData.value == null) {
            prepareParams()
        }
    } else {
        val intent = Intent(activity, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("fromScreen", 2)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

**prepareParams method**

```
  private fun prepareParams() {
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
        val params = mutableMapOf<String, String>()
        params["customer_id"] = preferenceUtils.getPreString(Constants.USER_ID)
        params["store"] = preferenceUtils.getPreInt(Constants.STORE).toString()
        wishlistViewModel.getWishList(params)
    } else {
        Utils.snackBar(binding.coordinatorWishlist, getString(R.string.network))
    }
}
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
val wishListLiveData: LiveData<Resource<WishlistModel>> get()  = repository.wishLiveData

fun getWishList(params: Map<String, String>) {
    repository.getWishlistApiCall(params)
}
```

**Repository Code**

```
private val wishListLiveData = MutableLiveData<Resource<WishlistModel>>()

val wishLiveData:LiveData<Resource<WishlistModel>> get() = wishListLiveData

fun getWishlistApiCall(params:Map<String,String>){
    if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(activity)) {
        wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Loading())
        retroService.getWishListApiCall(params).enqueue(object : Callback<WishlistModel> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<WishlistModel>, response: Response<WishlistModel>) {
                try {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            response.body()?.let {
                                if (it.code == 200) {
                                    if (it.status == "1") {
                                        wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Success(it))
                                    } else {
                                        wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(it.message))
                                    }
                                } else if (it.code == 404) {
                                    wishListLiveData.postValue(
                                        Resource.Error(
                                            activity.getString(
                                                R.string.four_hundred_four_not_found
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                } else if (it.code == 500) {
                                    wishListLiveData.postValue(
                                        Resource.Error(
                                            activity.getString(
                                                R.string.five_hundred_server_error
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(it.message))
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(response.message()))
                        }
                    } else {
                        wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(response.message()))
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(e.message.toString()))
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<WishlistModel>, t: Throwable) {
                try {
                    wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(t.message.toString()))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(e.message.toString()))
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        wishListLiveData.postValue(Resource.Error(activity.getString(R.string.network)))
    }
}
```

**ViewModelFactory Code**

```
class WishlistViewModelFactory(private val repository: WishlistRepository) :
ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return WishlistViewModel(repository) as T
}
}
```

**Remove wishlist observables**

```
    private fun removeObservables() {
    removeWishlistViewModel.removeWishListLiveData.observe(this) {
        when (it.status) {
            Status.LOADING -> {
                Utils.showDialog(activity)
            }
            Status.SUCCESS -> {
                Utils.hideDialog()
                if (it.data != null) {
                    it.data.let { removeWishModel ->
                        Utils.snackBar(
                            binding.coordinatorWishlist,
                            removeWishModel.message, Constants.SNACK_SUCCESS_COLOR
                        )
                        val activityFragmentMessageEvent =
                            Events.ActivityFragmentMessage("Wishlist")

                        EventBus.getDefault().post(activityFragmentMessageEvent)
                        prepareParams()
                    }
                }
            }
            Status.ERROR -> {
                Utils.hideDialog()
                Utils.snackBar(binding.coordinatorWishlist, it.errorMessage.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call prepareParams method again it's will make an API call of getting the wish-listed products. After that when I change the configuration from portrait to landscape it's starting again to make API calls again and again.

How can I resolve this issue? Please help me to resolve this issue with MVVM. I'm begginner in MVVM architecture.

Thank you

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My issue is when i change the configuration Actiivty onCreate() will be call whatever the code i have writtern in the onCreate() this will execute. In onCreate() have excecuted a method name prepareParams(). What it is doing prepareParam() will call the ViewModel() method and this method in ViewModel call the repository function which calling API.

Comment: I just want to manage when I remove any wishlist product in removeObservables() will execute a prepareParams() which again call the viewmodel function to refresh my list.

Comment: The problem is after remove any product from the wishlist i make api call to get the remaining product in the wishlist. When i change the configuration it's calling again and again. How can I resolve this.